# Unable to get mapping on Parblo MAST 22 graphics tablet

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, graphics-tablet

I'm using a custom built PC with a Maximus VI Impact motherboard with a Core i7 4770 and a Nvidia Gforce 760 video card and running windows 10

I'm running these monitors

[MAST 22](https://www.parblo.com/products/mast22) (1920x1080)(pen tablet) connected to Intel HD graphics 4600 -I've tried the latest and previous drivers
Toshiba LCD TV (1920x1080) connected to Nvidia Geforce 760
Crossover 289K (Tested at 1920x1080 and 3640x2160) Nvidia Geforce 760

Since installing the crossover 289K, I've been unable to calibrate the MAST 22 accurately - mapping is significantly off

[image: image showing how the mapping is off]

It seems to work correctly without the drive, but pressure sensitivity wouldn't work without it. I've tried the windows pen calibration tool as well, to no luck.

[image: image showing configuration screen]

How do I get this to work with my configuration?

Comment: Did you try using the MAST on the GTX instead and the other 1080P monitor on the HD graphics?

Comment: @NatsuKage I have, but it doesn't make a difference either way. The issue is that the Parblo would work fine for a few days, and then suddenly this issue would crop up for no reason. This is happening weekly at this point.

Comment: Have you tried a different quality of cable for it? Sometimes a bad quality cable cant sync correctly.  Also, does it do this without the new Crossover monitor?

Comment: @NatsuKage I've tried it with other cables (not brand new) and it's given me the same issue. It has also happened with a previous drawing monitor (XP-Pen brand) so I'm guessing it's an issue with my computer rather than the screens. 

I will still head out tomorrow to buy brand new cables to see if it helps, though, and I'll report back when I give it a try.